# How to run/deploy Spring Boot Microservice from IntelliJ into local Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, intellij-idea, kubernetes, microservices

I have a local Kubernetes cluster running, and I'm working on Spring Boot Microservices from IntelliJ. Is there a way I can deploy the Microservice Docker images directly into that Kubernetes cluster by just hitting 'Run' for regular development and debugging?

**WHY**
In the environment, one microservice can call another service with,

```
http://another-service:80
```

but everytime I need to run the service from local, I have to change all references to:

```
http://localhost:<some-port>
```

I understand I can use local config but there are similar issues. If I am able to do this, I can replicate production into the local machine as well.

I tried various IDE plugins, the docker files I have works fine into production but not sure what I can proceed with on local. I know this is quite wide question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use google [cloud code](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/install) extension plugin for IntelliJ to deploy spring boot apps to a Kubernetes cluster. This uses [skaffold](https://skaffold.dev) internally which handles the workflow for building, pushing and deploying your application to kubernetes cluster.

https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/deploying-a-k8-app

Comment: Let me give this a try. I will come back with an update soon.